# Take wchar_t and put into char?

Tags: c++

i've tried a few things and haven't yet been able to figure out how to get `const wchar_t *text` (shown bellow) to pass into the variable `StoreText` (shown below). What am i doing wrong?

```
void KeyboardComplete(int localClientNum, const wchar_t *text, unsigned int len)
{
    char* StoreText = text; //This is where error occurs
}
```

Comment: A `wchar_t` has 16 or 32 bits of information, a `char` can only hold 8 bits.  What do you want to do with the extra?  It is possible to convert but we need a little bit more infomation.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with `StoreText` after it is assigned?  It makes a big difference in how you assign/convert `text` to `StoreText`.

Comment: I am going to use it to display a dialog message, for example:
char* StoreText = text;
msgs::Dialog(StoreText );

Comment: That requires a data conversion from `wchar_t` characters to `char` characters.  It is not enough to just copy the pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly *assign* a `wchar_t*` to a `char*`, as they are different and incompatible data types.

If `StoreText` needs to point at the same memory address that `text` is pointing at, such as if you are planning on looping through the individual bytes of the `text` data, then a simple type-cast will suffice:

```
char* StoreText = (char*)text;
```

However, if `StoreText` is expected to point to its own separate copy of the character data, then you would need to *convert* the wide character data into narrow character data instead.  Such as by:

- using the [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) function on Windows:

  ```
  void KeyboardComplete(int localClientNum, const wchar_t *text, unsigned int len)
  {
      int StoreTextLen = 1 + WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, text, len, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
      std::vector<char> StoreTextBuffer(StoreTextLen);
      WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, text, len, &StoreTextBuffer[0], StoreTextLen, NULL, NULL);

      char* StoreText = &StoreText[0];
      //...
  }
  ```
- using the [`std::wcsrtombs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs) function:

  ```
  #include <cwchar>  

  void KeyboardComplete(int localClientNum, const wchar_t *text, unsigned int len)
  {
      std::mbstate_t state = std::mbstate_t();
      int StoreTextLen = 1 + std::wcsrtombs(NULL, &text, 0, &state);
      std::vector<char> StoreTextBuffer(StoreTextLen);
      std::wcsrtombs(&StoreTextBuffer[0], &text, StoreTextLen, &state);

      char *StoreText = &StoreTextBuffer[0];
      //...
  }
  ```
- using the [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) class (C++11 and later):

  ```
  #include <locale>

  void KeyboardComplete(int localClientNum, const wchar_t *text, unsigned int len)
  {
      std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> conv;
      std::string StoreTextBuffer = conv.to_bytes(text, text+len);

      char *StoreText = &StoreTextBuffer[0];
      //...
  }
  ```
- using similar conversions from the [ICONV](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org) library.

Answer (score 0):

`wchar_t` is a wide character. It is typically 16 or 32 bits per character, but this is system dependent.

`char` is a good ol' `CHAR_BIT`-sized data type. Again, how big it is is system dependent. Most likely it's going to be one byte, but I can't think of a reason why `CHAR_BIT` can't be 16 or 32 bits, making it the same size as wchar_t.

If they are different sizes, a direct assignment is doomed. For example an 8 bit `char` will see 2 characters, and quite likely 2 completely unrelated characters, for every 1 character in a 16 bit `wchar_t`. This would be bad.

Second, even if they are the same size, they may have different encodings. For example, the numeric value assigned to the letter 'A' may be different for the `char` and the `wchar_t`. It could be 65 in `char` and 16640 in `wchar_t`.

To make any sense in the different data type `char` and `wchar_t` will need to be translated to the other's encoding. [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) will often perform this translation for you, but [look into the locale library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/locale) for more complicated translations. Both require a compiler supporting C++11 or better. In previous C++ Standards, a [small army of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte) provided conversion support. Third party libraries such as [Boost::locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) are helpful to unify and provide wider support.

Conversion functions are supplied by the operating system to translate between the encoding used by the OS and other common encodings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for strings you should use `std::wstring/std::string` instead of raw pointers.

The C++11 Locale (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale) library can be used to convert wide string to narrow string.

I wrote a wrapper function below and have used it for years.  Hope it will be helpful to you, too.

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

std::string WstringToString(const std::wstring & wstr, const std::locale & loc /*= std::locale()*/)
{
    std::string buf(wstr.size(), 0);
    std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(loc).narrow(wstr.c_str(), wstr.c_str() + wstr.size(), '?', &buf[0]);
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: C++11 introduced a new [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) class to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring`. You are likely using a C++11 compiler already since a template definition cannot contain `>>` without whitespace in between the two `>` prior to C++11, that is a syntax error that was fixed in C++11 §14.2.3.

Answer (score -2):

You have to do a cast,  you can do this:

```
char* StoreText = (char*)text;
```

I think this may work.

But you can use the wcstombs function of cstdlib library.

```
char someText[12];
wcstombs(StoreText,text, 12);
```

> Last parameter most be a number of byte available in the array pointed.

Comment: 'If you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge.' -- Henry Spencer